# Using graph with on site exchange server

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My current project uses the EWS proxy API. I'd like to bring the code we utilize in EWS up to date and was thinking about importing the full EWS API. But I'm kind of wondering if Graph is a possible/better choice. We only have an on site exchange server, no hybrid or Office 365 stuff. We use EWS to grab emails from a specific folder and process them into a database. If Graph can handle on site only server tasks as good as or better than EWS would it be better to use Graph?

Comment: Looking at Graph documentation it doesn't look like an API that you'd import like EWS so I'm not sure if it's something we'd be able to utilize or not.

Comment: Graph is for O365 project. If you only have on site exchange server, the graph is not suitable for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph does not support on-premises versions of Exchange. There is planned work to support hybrid scenarios, but if you are not connected to Azure AD/Office 365 you won't be able to use it when it is supported. You will have to continue to use EWS API.